# Get the URLs of the article.text using Python Newspaper3k

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the national news from this web site. Following is my code.

```
from newspaper import Article

url = 'https://www.stuff.co.nz/national'
article = Article(url)
article.download()
article.parse()
data = article.text
data.splitlines()
```

In addition to the text heading, I need to get the urls of these. For example:

```
Fish sausages recalled People with egg allergies or an intolerance should not consume these products, MPI says

https://www.stuff.co.nz/business/118673724/fish-sausages-sold-in-auckland-and-hamilton-recalled-due-to-egg-allergy-risk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
import newspaper

url = 'https://www.stuff.co.nz/national'
paper = newspaper.build(url)

for article in paper.articles:
    target = article.title
    if target and len(target.strip())>0:
        print(target.strip().replace('\n',''))
        print(article.url)
```

Output:

```
Is a text worth a life?
https://www.stuff.co.nz/national/118315357/is-a-text-worth-a-life-a-message-to-kiwi-drivers-on-the-roads-this-holiday-season
Courtenay Place 'going backwards'
https://www.stuff.co.nz/national/118660168/wellington-police-commander-says-rowdy-courtenay-place-going-backwards
New frontier for energy?
https://www.stuff.co.nz/national/117860027/searching-for-new-zealands-electricity-future-in-the-deep-heat
```

etc.